# How do i rewrite this query without setting user variable inside expressions deprecated warning

Tags: mysql

How do i rewrite this query so that it wont produce setting user variables inside expressions deprecated warning ?

```
SET @i=0;
            SELECT battleId, userId,score,  @i:= @i+1 AS myRank 
             FROM battleparticipants  WHERE battleId=2 AND userId="gkfurcwsi033qzxg0u2bmj1ekebsklej"
             ORDER BY score DESC
```

Nodejs mysql library throws error because of this eventhough mysql bench just gives me warning.

Comment: What mysql version?

Comment: It must be MySQL 8.0, because that's when user variables inside expressions became deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function.

For example:

```
SELECT 
  battleId,
  userId,
  score,
  row_number() over(order by score desc) as myRank 
FROM battleparticipants  
WHERE battleId = 2 AND userId = "gkfurcwsi033qzxg0u2bmj1ekebsklej"
ORDER BY score DESC
```